# Using in from a group_concat

Tags: mysql

So I have two tables, one holding all users, and the other holding users with their corresponding groups. What I'm trying to do is to get all the user ids in the second table to get all the information I need from the first table. My explanation is a bit messy, but I think the code below should be clear enough

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    USER
WHERE
    id IN (
        SELECT
            group_concat(userid)
        FROM
            user_membership
        WHERE
            groupid = 45
    );
```

However, what returns is the empty set. When I replace the 'in' with an '=' it returns a single entry (as expected). What's wrong with my syntax? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `group_concat()` here as it concatenates every `userid` into a string column and you need to compare **each** `user.id` with a single `user_membership.userid` value, not an entire set. It's an overkill to perform that operation.

Simple select would suffice. However, it will probably be more efficient to rewrite your query using `EXISTS`:

```
select *
from user u
where exists (
  select 1
  from user_membership um
  where u.id = um.userid
    and groupid = 45
  )
```

If you really insist on the `IN` clause then correct query would look:

```
select *
from user
where id in (
  select userid
  from user_membership
  where groupid = 45
  )
```

Comment: It's much better to use the IN as the exist query took 2.22 seconds while the in version took 0.00. But thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is true. Remember that caching plays a big role here. You would need to run cold tests to compare performance. You can also add `EXPLAIN` clause at the beginning to see query execution plan for each of those queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FIND_IN_SET`

```
SELECT
 *
FROM USER
WHERE
FIND_IN_SET(id ,( SELECT group_concat(userid) FROM user_membership WHERE groupid = 45 ))
```

You can use `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT
    U.*
FROM USER U 
INNER JOIN user_membership UM ON UM.userid = U.id 
WHERE UM.groupid = 45
```

Or you can use `EXISTS` like Kamil G mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

`id` is a number, `group_concat` returns a string, containing all the ids separated by comma. I do not know the cause of the behavior you experienced, but I believe you could resolve the problem like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    USER
WHERE
    (
        SELECT
            CONCAT(',', CONCAT(group_concat(userid), ','))
        FROM
            user_membership
        WHERE
            groupid = 45
    ) LIKE CONCAT(',', CONCAT(id, ','));
```

Explanation: we write comma at the start and end of the inner result to allow `LIKE` to have a general operator. But your query can be optimized if you use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    USER
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            user_membership
        WHERE
            user_membership.groupid = 45 and user_membership.userid = USER.id
    );
```

Comment: Yeah, I think the problem was that it was a string (which I didn't realise), as I had previously used group_concat to retrieve information into a php script, which I then used to do something.

Comment: @A.Lau, yes, and it seems that there was a case when there is a single userid with the groupid you are searching for and in that case, with = you get the userid. I have shown you how you can make your code work and how you can simplify/optimize your code. Unfortunately I have left group_concat in the code, so the down-voter was right in down-voting. However, I have edited the answer to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks much more like a job for a join

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    USER u inner join 
     user_membership m on m.userid = u.id
WHERE
         m.groupid = 45
   ;
```

That should run much faster as the query can more easily use the index